# how to import database in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

i have my own created database is project.sql and now i want import this project.sql in phpmyadmin and it connected to my project in laravel 4.

So my question is that it is possible to import my database in to database and how to connect my laravel 4 project

How to migrate my database in laravel
If their is process to import and connect own created database in phpmyadmin and migrate to laravel 4 
please help me for this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to import directly your sql dump with Laravel unless you create a script specifically for it. You should use the [schema builder](http://laravel.com/docs/schema) to build migrations and then seed some date into it. You can even use [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to add some dummy data.

If for some reasons you really want to import your sql dump, I suggest that you do so using a mysql database manager like phpmyadmin or sequel pro for example.